# What does a norm $\|x\|$ goes to infinity mean?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am looking into Coercive functions.

The definition says :
A continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}$ is called coercive if
$$\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = + \infty$$

1. What does a *norm* to *infinity* mean?
2. I have two functions one of which is coercive and another not. I have trouble deciphering the difference.
   $$i)\space g(x) = x_1^6 + 5x_2^4 + x_3 - 3x_1x_2x_3^3; \space x \epsilon \mathbb{R}^3\implies \text{not  coercive}\\
   ii)\space h(x) = x_1^4 + x_2^4 - 3x_1^3 + x_2; \space x \epsilon \mathbb{R}^2 \implies \text{coercive}$$

Comment: What is $n$ in your examples? Is it the same for both examples?

Comment: @SPK He probably means $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Still the same question.

Comment: To elaborate on @SPK's question: The function $f(x) = x_1^2$ is coercive for $n=1$, but not for $n=2$, because $\Vert (0, n)\Vert \to \infty$, but $f(0,n) = 0 \not\to \infty$.

Comment: Re 1.: All vectors $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert = R$ lie on a "sphere" $S_R$ with radius $R$ (depending on the metric $\lVert.\rVert$ it might be actually a box, a diamond or ..). The limit process goes then towards infinite radius. On that inflating surface $S_R$ the function values $f(x)$ for $x \in S_R$ go towards infintiy as well. Nate's answer of course is the mathematically more precise one.

Comment: @SPK I have mentioned $n$.

Answer (score 6):

For every $a$ there exists $b$ such that for every $x$ with $\|x\| >b$, we have $f(x)>a$.

Comment: I don't think this explains why the first example is not coercive. You can take $\mathbf{x}=(R,0,0)$ and let $R$ going to infinity. This satisfies your condition, but still $g$ is not coercive. The keyword here is *direction*.

Comment: @SPK: There was an implicit universal quantifier. I've rephrased to make it more clear.

Comment: @NateEldridge: Thank you. It's very clear now.

Comment: This seems to be the popular answer, but I have trouble using this definition to find if a function is coercive or not. Sorry, if I miss the obvious, I am a newb.

Answer (score 4):

A norm going to infinity can be seen as the length of a vector going to infinity, i.e. an infinitely long "arrow" starting at the origin.

According to your definition a function is then coercive if the function value also go to infinity, *independent of the direction of the vector*.

So your second example is coercive in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because for the norm going to infinity, either $x_1$, $x_2$ (or both) should go to infinity. Since both $x_1$ and $x_2$ have positive dominating fourth order terms also $h$ goes to infinity.

Your first example is not coercive in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because if you take $\mathbf{x}=(1,1,R)$ and you let $R$ going to infinity, the norm of $\mathbf{x}$ will go to infinity, but because of the negative dominating third order term, $g$ will not go to infinity.

Comment: It seems to me that I have to find examples of $X$ to check if a function can go to infinity or not. This might help in cases when we are trying to prove that a function is not coercive (just find an example). But proving a function is coercive for some examples doesn't mean I can say that it is coercive for $all X$. Could you help me with this dilemma? Thanks!

Comment: @user2761431: You can show it just like I showed it for the second example. If the norm of your vector goes to infinity, at least one of the components must go to infinity. Because the dominant terms (in this case for both components) are even, they are always positive. Therefore $h$ will go to infinity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit limits are most easily understood in terms of sequences. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{||x||\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty
\end{equation}
is equivalent to saying that for every sequence $(x_n)$ we have
\begin{equation}
||x_n|| \stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty \quad\Rightarrow \quad f(x_n) \stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

A hint for 2.:

"Coercive" means that $f(x)$ is **large positive** when $\|x\|$ is large. Now one of the two given functions can even be large negative for suitable $x$ far away from the origin. For the other function you have to prove that the highest degree terms in any case outweigh the other terms when $\|x\|$ is large, so that only the contribution of the highest degree terms counts in the limit.